# Vim claims Eclim’s ProjectCreate is not an editor command

Tags: eclim

I followed [eclim’s installation instructions](http://eclim.org/install.html), but when [getting started](http://eclim.org/gettingstarted.html) I can’t even create a project :

```
:ProjectCreate /path/to/project
E492: Not an editor command: ProjectCreate
```

What’s wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the eclim installer suggestion to install vimfiles in `~/.vim/bundle/eclim` ?  By default (at least on Debian) `vim` won’t look into this directory.  You have to move eclim’s vimfiles (directories `eclim` and `plugins`) directly into `~/.vim/` (merge `plugins` if it already exists).

Alternatively, I didn’t test it but [the "build from source" tutorial](http://eclim.org/install.html) suggests to

> create a `user.properties` file at the eclim source root and put all your properties in there:
>
> ```
> $ vim user.properties
> eclipse.home=/opt/eclipse
> eclipse.local=${user.home}/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_<version>
> vim.files=${user.home}/.vim/bundle/eclim
> ```